# using array.includes in vue application

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to get my vue app to work where it shows/hides values based on selected options (from a multiselect) and everything with the select and a function it's calling has been working.

However, when I try to use `includes` in my v-if on the html, it says it can't read properties of undefined, reading includes.

Am I calling the includes or the testArray incorrectly here?

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  props: { 

  },
  components: {Multiselect: window.VueMultiselect.default},
  data: {
    tiers:[
      {name: "test tier"}
    ],
    selectedTier: [],
    values: [
      {name: "adam", tier: "test tier"},
      {name: "sam", tier:"none"}
    ]
  },
  checkTier(){
    console.log(this.selectedTier);

    let testArray = [];

    this.selectedTier.forEach(fields => {
      this.testArray.push(fields.name);
    });
    console.log(this.testArray);
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-multiselect@2.1.0"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/vue-multiselect@2.1.0/dist/vue-multiselect.min.css">


<div id="app">

<div class="uk-width-2-10" style="position:relative;">
    <multiselect
      v-model="selectedTier"
      :options="tiers"
      :multiple="true"
      :close-on-select="true"
      placeholder="All Tiers"
      label="name"
      track-by="name"
      @input="checkTier"
    ></multiselect>
</div>

<div v-for="value in values">
  <div v-if="testArray.includes(value.tier)">
    <p>Working</p>
  </div>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: You are creating a new variable with `let testArray = []`, as opposed to a property on your Vue instance. Create it as a data property (in `data()`) and push into it like you are now.

Comment: "can't read x of undefined" means there's `something.x` in your code and `something` is `undefined`

Comment: @CharlieSchliesser If I do that, then it seems to work to push, but the existing version also takes them out if I deselect them and it doesn’t allow to push duplicates. If I make testArray a data property, how could I prevent duplicates from being pushed? I’ll look into a multi select call to remove them if I de-select

Answer (score 1):

As [Chalie Schliesser](https://stackoverflow.com/users/630614/charlie-schliesser) said in the comments:

> Create it as a data property (in data()) and push into it like you are now

With regards to a unique array there are a couple ways to do this:

1. `const unique = (array) => [...new Set(array)];`

You should then be able to call `unique` and have a unique array.

2. You could create a function that takes in an array and a key that you're concerned and loop through them.
   Lets say our array looked like this:

```
const array = [
  {title: 'Fancy pants'},
  {title: 'New fancy title'},
  {title: 'Fancy pants'}
]
```

then we could do something like this:

```
const removeDuplicates = (array, key) => {
  const check = {};
  const res = [];

  array.forEach(element => {
    if (!check[element[key]]) {
      check[element[key]] = true;
      const label = element.title;
      const value = element.title.toLowerCase();
      const search = element.title.toLowerCase();
      res.push({ label, value, search });
    }
  });
  return res;
};
```

Running:

```
console.log(removeDuplicates(array, 'title'))
```

should give us the following output:

```
const array = [
  {title: 'Fancy pants'},
  {title: 'New fancy title'}
]
```

Comment: `Set` won't work as is because objects aren't equal